# C# - API for RTC Alarm

Tags: c#, .net, api

I want to program my computer to start automatically at several time intervals. From what I've looked over the internet, I can do this by using the RTC alarm of my motherboard. I would like to do this on my laptop, which does not have an RTC alarm section in BIOS.

Is there any API in C# for programming the RTC alarm clock of the motherboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows API `CreateWaitableTimer` can wake the machine.  Windows uses ACPI to communicate this request to the BIOS, which sets up the real-time clock.

More information here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49798/Wake-the-PC-from-standby-or-hibernation
- http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/6/18/wake-up-from-sleep-createwaitabletimer-in-c.html

Comment: I have managed to to this via sleep but I was wondering whether I can do this while the computer is shut down. Do you know something about this?